# Google OAuth2 remembering user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth, youtube-api, google-account

I have been dabbling with the OAuth2 api Google offer in their Objective-C library.

Anyway, I am having troubles understanding how I get the app to remember who logged in. I have successfully gotten authentication working using the following.

I Call the below method to present the OAuth view controller from Google, the user signs in, and I'm authenticated. However, every time I relaunch the app, its runs the login screen again, as though I am not authenticated. As I understand it, I need to have some sort of keychain/token remembrance in place so that it recognises the user recently signed in.

But how? I can't work it out from the little documentation available.

```
-(void)authenticateUserFromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeYouTube
                                                                clientID:kClientID
                                                            clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                        keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                delegate:self
                                                        finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

    [viewController.navigationController pushViewController:authViewController animated:YES];
}

-(void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error != nil)
    {
        // Authentication failed
        NSLog(@"Failed to authorise");
    }
    else
    {
        // Authentication succeeded
        NSLog(@"Authorised");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the Objective-C library, but maybe [this tutorial](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/tutorials/ios-oauth2-tutorial) could be useful. It says you need to call [GTMOAuth2Authentication accessToken], it seems that's what you're missing. For more information about the OAuth 2.0 flow : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

Comment: For a working example of this check out their [github](https://github.com/KinveyApps/Kinvey-OAuth2-DI-Sample).  Test their code against yours and see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: There's also something in the [Google reference](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction#Retrieving_Authorization_from_the_Keychain) about the Keychain.

Comment: I'd recommend editing your answer and including your reference link with a simple explanation. Also take a look at the [section just above it](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction#Using_the_Authentication_Tokens).  This section talks about how to store the OAuth token so it can be fetched (which is good to know!).

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the Objective-C library, but maybe [this part of the Google Reference](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction#Using_the_Authentication_Tokens) could be useful. It explains how to use the authentication tokens and how to handle the Keychain when the user relaunches the app.